# Use Radio value to set class background color?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, background-color

novice here.

Trying to find a way to get the value of the checked radio button (formatted as a Hex Code) to be the background-color of a specific class. Basically, I have a box that I'd like the user to be able to customize and setting the color of elements based on radio selection is crucial to making it work. Here's what I have so far:

```
<form id="2019-Holiday" name="2019-Holiday" data-name="2019 Holiday" class="form">
<input type="radio" name="box-color" value="#177262" data-name="box-color" id="177262">
<input type="radio" name="box-color" value="#80a44a" data-name="box-color" id="80a44a">
</form>

<div class=box-color" id="box-color">
    <div class="box-background-color" id="box-wall1"></div>
    <div class="box-background-color" id="box-wall2"></div>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("box-color").onclick = function() {
        boxBackgroundColor();
    };

    function boxBackgroundColor() {
        var ele = document.getElementsByName("box-color");
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box-background-color"); // get all elements
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
                if (ele[i].checked)
                    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = ele[i].value;
            }
    }
</script>
```

I know that the checked radio bit is working, but the background color of the class part seems to break it. Any help would be appreciated!

Edited to add form/html elements.

Comment: What is the .value set as? It needs to be a valid background colour value. like `#ffffff` or `rgb(255,255,255)` for example. Also, be wary of your nested loops sharing the same iteration value `i`.

Comment: please add your HMTL part of this ( all `<form>` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a onClick-handler to a specific div, I would rather set an onChange-handler for the form itself and get the selected value whenever a radiobutton has changed.

Also, the ID `2019-Holiday` is not valid, as IDs cant start with a number.

```js
document.querySelector('#Holiday-2019').onchange = function(e) {
  var selectedColor = e.target.value;
  boxBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
};

function boxBackgroundColor(selectedColor) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box-background-color"); // get all elements
      
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
  }        
}
```

```css
form {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
#box-color {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
}

.box-background-color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="Holiday-2019" class="form">
  <input type="radio" name="box-color" value="#177262" id="177262"> Dark green
  <input type="radio" name="box-color" value="#80a44a" id="80a44a">Light green
</form>

<div id="box-color">
  <div class="box-background-color" id="box-wall1">Boxwall1</div>
  <div class="box-background-color" id="box-wall2">Boxwall2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How I code this ( if it help ?)

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')

myForm.onchange=_=>
  {
  document.body.style.background = myForm['box-color'].value;
  }
```

```css
body { background-color: white;  }
label { display: block; width:200px; background-color: grey; margin: 0.5em;}
```

```html
<form action="xxx" id="my-form">
  <label><input type="radio" name="box-color" value="white" checked > white</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="box-color" value="blue" > blue</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="box-color" value="red" > red</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="box-color" value="green" > green</label>
</form>
```

And to style a specific class: ( just **4 lines of code** )

```js
const Root    = document.documentElement
    , myForm  = document.querySelector('#my-form')

myForm.onchange=_=>
  {
  Root.style.setProperty('--bg-color', myForm['box-color'].value)
  }
```

```css
:root {
  --bg-color  : blue;
}

.myDivClass{
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  display         : inline-block;
  margin          : 1em;
  width           : 100px;
  height          : 100px;
}

label {
  display         : inline-block;
  width           : 5.5em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin          : 0.3em;
  padding         : .5em .2em;
  border          : 1px solid black;
  border-radius   : .5em;
  text-transform  : capitalize;
  line-height     : 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDivClass"></div>
<div class="myDivClass"></div>
<div class="myDivClass"></div>
<div class="myDivClass"></div>

<form action="xxx" id="my-form">
  <label><input type="radio" name="box-color" value="blue" checked> blue  </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="box-color" value="red"  > red   </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="box-color" value="green"> green </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I'm trying to style a specific class, not the body

Comment: @JoshJacobs well, I have added a new code for this case

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function changeColor(e) {
            // by ID
            document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = e.value;

            // by className
            let element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(element, function (el) {
                el.style.backgroundColor = e.value;
            });
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="color" class="radio" value="#FF0000" id="" onchange="changeColor(this)">red
        <input type="radio" name="color" class="radio" value="yellow" id="" onchange="changeColor(this)">yellow
        <input type="radio" name="color" class="radio" value="green" id="" onchange="changeColor(this)">green

    </div>
    <div id="box" class="box" style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color: black;">

    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: first blush this looks like it should work, but I ran it in codepen and doesn't function? Please clarify :)

Comment: @JoshJacobs can you specify the error you are getting.